# You toss a fair coin 1000 times and take a step forward if the coin lands head and a step backward if it lands tail.

Tags: probability

You toss a fair coin  1000  times and take a step forward if the coin lands head and a step backward if it lands tail. Upper bound the probability that you end up  ≥100  steps from your starting point (in either direction) using Chernoff bound

when i try to solve it using chernoff bound my delta becomes negative i think i am definitely doing something wrong and how do i approach the problem ?

Comment: Try posting your attempt, it makes it easier to spot mistakes.

Comment: If you could edit your question to include your work, we can help address what went wrong.